# How to target image inside a div with an id with getelementbyid/tag/name?

Tags: javascript

Basically I want to change smiley.gif to landscape.jpg without changing divs and tags, but this code is not working. 
Any suggestions?

```
<div id="foo">
<div id="bar"><img src="smiley.gif">
Hello world!
</div>
</div>
<script>
getElementById("bar").getElementsByTagName("img").src="landscape.jpg";

</script>
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there were: 1. A toolbar of formatting aids. 2. A big orange box giving the top tips for formatting. 3. A live preview of your question you could use to see what it would look like before posting. Worth using. :-)

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns _HTMLCollection_ in _IE_ and in _webkit_ it returns _nodeList_!

Comment: Is `img` always the `firstChild` of the element with the `id` of `bar`? And if so, will that image `src` always be `smiley.gif`, or can it vary?

Comment: yes its firstchild with the id bar. and it will be smiley.gif

Comment: Then you can do `document.getElementById('bar').firstElementChild.src = 'landscape.jpg';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be better if you assign ID to img tag and use it like this

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"><img src="smiley.gif" id="myImg"> Hello world! </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myImg").src="landscape.jpg";
</script>
```

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pravins/fsqzw/)1**

or Use this

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar"><img src="smiley.gif"> Hello world! </div>
</div>
<script>
   var obj = document.getElementById("foo");
   if(obj != null)
   {
      var images = obj.getElementsByTagName('img');
      images[0].src = 'landscape.jpg';
   }
</script>
```

Comment: thats the trick... cant edit the html but only script.. its a part of my tutorial hence I dont want to put up whole thing

Comment: yes this way it works fine! but im not allowed to edit the html code.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` is a method that you can only call on the document. `getElementsByTagName` will return a nodelist, and you need the first element in that nodelist:

```
document.getElementById("bar").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src="landscape.jpg";
// Note the `[0]` here -----------------------------------^^^
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/we3ag/)

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you get any errors in the console? Is the DOM ready when the script is processed? Can you demonstrate your issue?

Comment: im running it here http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_image

Comment: Please don't use that, use JSFiddle - or even better, create and run your own files.

Comment: yeah i got aptana and and got it working with        document.getElementById('bar').firstElementChild.src = 'landscape.jpg';

Answer (score 0):

As you have confirmed that the layout is fixed, then simply use.

```
document.getElementById('bar').firstElementChild.src = 'landscape.jpg';
```

This basically finds the unique element named `bar`, chooses the first child element (not [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild), which could be an empty text node) and assigns the new value to `src`

Documentation on MDN

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

[firstElementChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.firstElementChild)